# How to Change TeXShop dictionary to American English?

Tags: texshop, dictionaries

How can I change the TeXShop dictionary to American English?! It is set to British English! It might be the whole mac's dictionary that is being used, I am not sure. In that case, how can I change it in the system?!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The default language is the one chosen in the “Language & Text” System Preferences pane, where you can set the region to “British”. Or you can choose the language in the TeXShop Edit menu (“Show Spelling and Grammar”, that in the picture becomes “Hide”)

[image]

A *more elegant solution* (in case you are dealing with multiple languages or locales and want to change on a file-specific manner) would be to add this at the start of the `.tex` file:

`% !TEX spellcheck = fr-FR`

Replace `fr-FR` with `en-US` or other choices as necessary!

Comment: Changing the system wide choice is not practical, especially if you work on several documents in parallel, one in one language, one in another. (either both in Texshop or only one in Texshop and the other in another software)

Comment: I tried the second solution : it changed the language of the existing text but whatever I add to the open document is considered as belonging to the old language.

Comment: @Arnaud Did you try adding `% !TEX spellcheck = fr-FR` at the beginning of the file? Or the suitable string, of course, such as `en_UK` or `en_US`.

Comment: To egreg : fantastic, thanks! Open file, add line, close file, open file again, I guess the procedure could be easier but it is simple enough.

Answer (score 3):

Go "Textshop" => "Services" => "Services Preferences" => "Text"
Inside "Text" page, click "spelling" on the right.

Comment: This will also show all the available languages that the spell check can function in. (I was surprised to see Spanish isn't there.)