# Use american english as standard in LaTeX

Tags: languages, texshop

My latex editor (TeXshop, macbook) always uses UK english. I can change this but then next time I restart LaTeX it is the same problem again, UK english. How can one permanently change to american english?

Comment: Possibly useful: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/129598/21344

Comment: Please distinguish between LaTeX and your TeX-editor! For LaTeX you may use the `babel` package. But I guess, you should clarify your question. This seems to be an editor issue.

Comment: I don't think it's true. By default, LaTeX uses the hyphenation patterns for American English. Perhaps you're referring to the spelling checker used by TeXShop. This is not a TeX problem: go to the Keyboard pane of the System Preferences; in the “Text” tab, pull the “Automatic by language” drop down menu and click “Set up” at the bottom; then change the order between UK English and US English, checking the latter.